# How to open one by one link in new Tab from Menu using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to open one by one link in new Tab in selenium Java, but only one link is opening the first time but For Loop goes wrong when open a second link, can anyone please help me to figure this out.

Here is my Code.

```
public class Link_Open_In_New_Tab {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void OpenBrowser() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void OpenLink() throws InterruptedException {

        List<WebElement> ProMenu;
        WebElement SubLinks;
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/a")).click();
        ProMenu = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/ul[@class='sublist']/li/a"));

        for (int i = 0; i < ProMenu.size(); i++) {

            SubLinks = driver
                    .findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[" + (i + 1) + "]/ul[@class='sublist']/li/a"));
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(SubLinks).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            }

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            driver.close();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/a")).click();
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: See this "for (int i = 0; i < ProMenu.size(); i++)" when i run the script then only first menu is openeing in new Tab, but when i switch to the previous menu then noting happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to open all the sublinks from the product menu. But your sublink xpath is pointing to the first sublink of all the menu (`li[" + (i + 1) + "]/ul[@class='sublist']/li/a`). So, you need to modify your sublink xpath as below and then try

```
SubLinks = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/ul[@class='sublist']/li[" + (i + 1) + "]/a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to **hover** on **Product**, to get all the `sub menus items`. After then you can simulate keyboard strokes using **Actions** class which is available in **Selenium** and **JAVA**.

You can try this **code** :

```
public class Ashish  {

    static WebDriver driver ; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/a"))).build().perform();  
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/ul[@class='sublist']/li/a"));
        for(WebElement ele:element) {
            action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).moveToElement(ele).click().keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();
        }


        }
}
```

**UPDATE 1** :

```
public class Ashish  {

    static WebDriver driver ; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user***\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.nopcommerce.com/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/a"))).build().perform();  
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='top-menu']/li[1]/ul[@class='sublist']/li/a"));
        System.out.println(element.size());
        for(int i = 0 ; i<element.size() ; i++) {
            action.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element.get(i)))).click().keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();
            ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
        }


        }
}
```

Console output :

```
9
nopCommerce - ASP.NET free shopping cart solution. What is nopCommerce?
nopCommerce - ASP.NET Open-source Ecommerce Shopping Cart Solution
nopCommerce - ASP.NET open source eCommerce solution. Feature list.
nopCommerce - Shopping Cart Demo & Shopping Cart Solution
nopCommerce - open source shopping cart. Showcase. Live Shops.
nopCommerce - open source shopping cart. Case Studies and Success Stories.
nopCommerce - ASP.NET open source shopping cart. Roadmap.
nopCommerce copyright removal key - nopCommerce
The nopCommerce Public License Version 3.0 ("NPL") - nopCommerce
```

Comment: You want to open every sub menus items in new tab , right ?

Comment: Thanks but this is not full fill my requirement, see below steps which i need to perform.
1. Open URL
2. Hover on Product Menu
3. Open First Link in New Windown
4. Back to the First window
5. Open Product Menu again
6. Open Second link in new Window
7. Same for all other links..

Comment: Is there any special use case ? or why don't you just open all the sub menu items at one shot ?

Comment: I am trying to verify all pages Title one by one. I am learning selenium so i created steps by own and trying to converting that steps in Automation.

Comment: Not Working.. It throwing "Index 1 out-of-bounds for length 1".

Comment: nopCommerce - ASP.NET free shopping cart solution. What is nopCommerce?
nopCommerce - ASP.NET Open-source Ecommerce Shopping Cart Solution
nopCommerce - ASP.NET open source eCommerce solution. Feature list.
nopCommerce - Shopping Cart Demo & Shopping Cart Solution
nopCommerce - open source shopping cart. Showcase. Live Shops.
nopCommerce - open source shopping cart. Case Studies and Success Stories.
nopCommerce - ASP.NET open source shopping cart. Roadmap.
nopCommerce copyright removal key - nopCommerce
The nopCommerce Public License Version 3.0 ("NPL") - nopCommerce

Comment: That is the console output at my end.

Comment: @AshishSavaliya : Added new code with explicit wait too. Hope this one will work at your end. Please get the code from UPDATE1 section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to test the links title to be working as expected or not then why need to you Crtl+click.

As per development, link here is to click but not ctrl+click, personally i am not willing to do this action.

Create variable say int i=1;

in loop like used, go for normal click and verify title. then increment i and go for browser back.